# How to remove the blank line at the end of the page

Tags: unix, hiveql

I am storing the output of a hive query into file, when copy the file to local and open i can see one blank line available at the end .Please help me to remove the line.

Comment: What did you try? Something like `sed '$d'` or `grep -Ev "^$"` ?

Comment: @walter already tried this still getting one blank line ,and tried of manually removing this when saving the csv again getting the same blank line at the end

Comment: When you open the csv with a text editor, not Excel, do you see separators?
(Both commands: add `> converted.csv` and look for the differences)